# Expectation of random variable with differently weighted realizations

Tags: probability, statistics, expected-value, means

Let $Y=wX$, where $X$ is a random variable with mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2$, and $w$ is the weight which could change for every realization of $Y$. In other words, $N$ realizations of $Y$ are given as $y_n$ = $w_n x_n,~n=1,...,N$. The weights $w_n,~\forall n$, are assumed to be $N$ uniformly spaced samples of a positive continuous function $W(t),~0<t<T$.

I wonder how can we express the population mean $E[Y]$?

My guess is that $E[Y]$ is defined as $E[Y]=\bar{w}E[X]=\bar{w}\mu$, where $\bar{w}=\frac{1}{T}\int^T_0 W(t) dt$.

Does that reasoning make sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Expectation of $Y$ is conditioned with the numbers of samples $n$ so

$$E(w|n) = \bar{w} = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}w_{n}$$

and so just use it in

$$E(Y|n) = E(w|n)E(X)$$.

You don't need the average of W because some values are irrelevant given a number $n$. Your calculation might only be APPROXIMATELY true if $w_{n}$  is near $W(T)$ and $n$ must be very large too.

Comment: That makes sense. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Essentially $Y=wX$ is a product of two independent random variables so $E(Y)=E(w)E(X)$ where $E(w)=\overline{w}$.

Comment: That is how I was thinking at first, but then I realized that $w$ is deterministic (there is nothing random about it) since $W(t)$ is known. Given the number of realizations, we can say which values $w_n,~\forall n$, are going to take exactly. This is why I think the average value of $W(t)$ needs to be calculated.

Comment: $W(t)/T$ is the density function for $w$.  Giving them different names doesn't really change anything.